# Writing a product images updater for Magento 1.9.2.4, script seems to quit after the 3rd line of php in here

Tags: php, magento

Here's the whole script.php:

```
require_once('../app/Mage.php'); Mage::init();
$fbn = ($_GET['fbn']) ? trim(htmlencode($_GET['fbn'])) : null;
if (is_null($fbn)) die("specify filebasename in url (?fbn= )");

$file = __DIR__."/csv/{$fbn}.csv"; echo $file; var_dump($_GET);

class UpdateProductGallerySelects
{
    public function __construct($file, $num = 0)
    {
        if (!file_exists($file)) die('no good file');

        $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($file));
        array_walk($csv, function(&$a) use ($csv) {
          $a = array_combine($csv[0], $a);
        }); array_shift($csv);

        foreach ($csv as $row) $this->updateProduct($row); 
    }

    private function updateProduct($r)
    {
        $p = null; print_r($r);
        $p = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($r['sku'], 'sku');
        $g = $p->getMediaGalleryImages('images');
        $ct = count($g); echo $p->getName()." {{$ct}}\n";
    }
}
$set = new UpdateProductGallerySelects($file, 10);
```

This runs up to the first die(), apparently, which does print if `$fbn` is null.

Please tell me what's wrong.

Comment: `$fbn` is null, that's what is wrong.

Comment: Magento 1.x supports writing CLI scripts. You can can simply add the file inside `shell/` dir and extend `shell/abstract.php` which will bootstrap the app, initialize autoloader and parse command line arguments for you.

That way, you don't have to trigger it by making http, instead you can simply `php shell/update-product-galleries --fbn xxxx`.

Answer (score 0):

You must check your $_GET['fbn'] as it seems you are not getting anything in this variable. You must pass some value in it and then check.